# Python Expandable Conditional Count

Tags: python, pandas, count, conditional-statements

I need a count of how many times different variable occur in a dataframe. 
Here's a representation of the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'game_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                   'event_num': list(range (0,10)), 
                   'event_cd': np.random.randint(25, size = 10)})
```

Output:

```
   event_cd  event_num  game_id
0        20          0        1
1         0          1        1
2        15          2        1
3         8          3        1
4        10          4        1
5        18          5        2
6        22          6        2
7         7          7        2
8         7          8        2
9        23          9        2
```

Suppose I have a formula:

```
some_stat = (count(event_cd = 10) + count(event_cd = 14)) / count(event_cd = 2)
```

What would be the most efficient way to go about this? The actual data does contain 24 different event_cd's, and contains roughly 50,000 rows. If possible, the counts also need to correspond to a game_id, so game 1 would have different counts than game 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `sum` of `boolean mask`:

```
some_stat = ((df.event_cd == 10).sum() + (df.event_cd == 14).sum()) /
             (df.event_cd == 2).sum()

print (some_stat)
```

If want also count per groups use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function:

```
def f(x):
    return ((x == 10).sum() + (x == 14).sum()) / (x == 2).sum()

df = df.groupby('game_id')['event_cd'].apply(f)
print (df)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly; thank you. Now, suppose I want to count a new variable from another field, say event_outs. Then


`some_stat = ((df.event_cd == 10).sum() + (df.event_cd == 14).sum()) 
                         /df.event_outs.sum()`


I tried


`def f(x,y):
    return ((x == 10).sum() + (x == 14).sum()) / (y.sum())


df = df.groupby('game_id')['event_cd', 'event_outs].apply(f)
print (df)`

But received an error that f is missing an argument.

Comment: You need `def f(x): return ((x['event_cd'] == 10).sum() + (x['event_cd'] == 14).sum()) / (x['event_outs'].sum()) df = df.groupby('game_id').apply(f) print (df)`

Comment: I have one more, hopefully, final question. Suppose that the above 2 games are just part of a series, where we have many more series. Would it be possible to return just the stat for each game 1? If we group by game_id, the output is for each game combined, instead of each individual game. But I'd like to store each individual game stat in another dataframe.

Comment: Not sure if understand, maybe the best is create new question. thanks.